# English statement to logic expression

Tags: logic

Which of the following formulas represents the sentence, 'Share prices will go up, and if interest rates go up too, there will be a recession', where ;

p means 'share prices will go up'

q means 'interest rates will go up'

r means 'there will be a recession'.

(A)p∧q→r

(B)p∧(q→r)

(C)p→q∧r

(D)(p→q)∨r

I am confused to choose between A and B, because of "too".

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say B, as the statement implies that share prices will definitely go up, and A is not saying that.

Comment: @Bram-Thanks.Got it. :)

Comment: @user3767495 You're welcome! :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not D since if share prices go up this doen't mean that the intrest rates will go up.

It is not C since it is saying that (if p) then (...) and p doesn't need an 'if' in this case because it is always true, it can't be false (i.e. share prices **will** go up and there is no chance that they won't).

And similarly it is not A, since it start with (if p and q are both true) then (...), which means that A gives a chance that [(p is false) or (q is false)] which migh imply that (p is false) but as we just said for part C, p is always true and it can't be false.

So I also see that part B is the right answer, and we can understand its statement as (p is true) **and** (if q is true then r is true) i.e. (share prices will go up) **and** (if interest rates will go up then there will be a reccession)